# More info on SearchView suggestions

Tags: android, sqlite, searchview

Yo yo, I got a question for you guys:

So, I'm implementing this searchView suggestion function in my app. But I can't get enough information displayed on each row as I wanted to:

[image]

As you can see, I only have initial and gender on there, I want more info like age and ID etc,.

The information is stored in an SQLite database within the app, and I'm pulling that info out through the code below:

```java
    public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);

        // This HashMap is used to map table fields to Custom Suggestion fields
        mAliasMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // Unique id for the each Suggestions ( Mandatory )
        mAliasMap.put("_ID", COLUMN_ID + " as " + "_id" );

        // Text for Suggestions ( Mandatory )
        mAliasMap.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1, COLUMN_INITIAL + " as " + SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1);

        mAliasMap.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2, COLUMN_GENDER + " as " + SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2);

    }

    /** Returns patients for suggestions */
    public Cursor getPatients(String[] selectionArgs){

        String selection = COLUMN_INITIAL + " like ? ";

        if(selectionArgs!=null){
            selectionArgs[0] = "%"+selectionArgs[0] + "%";
        }

        SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        queryBuilder.setProjectionMap(mAliasMap);

        queryBuilder.setTables(TABLE_PATIENTS);

        Cursor c = queryBuilder.query(getReadableDatabase(),
                new String[] { "_ID",
                        SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1,
                        SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2 } ,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                null,
                null,
                COLUMN_INITIAL + " asc ","10"
        );
        return c;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. Layout

create a **rowLayout.xml** which represents each row of suggestion (in your case 4 textview for name, gender, age, more info.)

2. In java

**`List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();`**

```java
     for (int i=0;i<totalNoOfSuggestion;i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                hm.put("name",name);
                hm.put("gender", gender);
                hm.put("age", age);
                hm.put("moreInfo", moreInfo);
                aList.add(hm);
            }

    String[] from = { "name","gender","age","moreInfo"};
    
        int[] to = { R.id.name,R.id.gender,R.id.age,R.id.moreInfo};
                SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(),aList,R.layout.rowLayout,from,to);
    
    autoComplete.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
```

Here we are creating a List of Strings and giving id to them.

We have created a Hashmap of Strings and then added it to the List.

Then we have created a `String[] from` which contains all the id's which we have used in Hashmap.

Then we have created `int[] to` which contains all the id's of textview in our **rowLayout.xml**.

Then `SimpleAdapter` whose first argument is `Context` the second one is `List` third one is `Layout` fourth one is **Array of Id's used in `List`** and the fifth one is **id's used in xml**.

Then we `setAdapter` to our `autoComplete Textview`.

Hope you have understood.